# memory leak in python script for blender

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-3.x, blender

I'm fairly new to python (I normally use c++). I have written a python script to convert a Blender object into a binary mask file using a ray-tracing algorithm.

I am ending up with a huge memory leak. For M = 512 (shown below), the script increases RAM usage as the script runs, with the end result being a whopping 5.7GB being used. This RAM usage also remains after the script has run, until I close Blender.

I'm not sure if the `open()` command stores the open file in RAM (I'm guessing it does), but this would only account for 256MB of RAM usage, as that is the resulting filesize, and also does not explain why the RAM usage remains after `fo.close()`.

I'm sure there is something very simple I am missing, but not being very familiar with python, I'm having a hard time working out what it is. I've tried clearing all the variables used in the `pointInsideMesh()` function by putting the lines

```
axis  = None
mat1  = None
mat   = None
orig  = None
count = None
location = None
normal   = None
index    = None
outside1 = None
outside2 = None
```

immediately before the `return` statement, but this has not plugged the memory leak. Here is my code:

```
import mathutils, numpy, bpy





def pointInsideMesh(point,ob):

    axes = [ mathutils.Vector((1,0,0)) ]
    outside1 = False
    for axis in axes:

        mat1 = mathutils.Matrix(ob.matrix_world)
        mat=mat1.invert()

        orig = mat1*point


        count = 0
        while True:
            location,normal,index = ob.ray_cast(orig,axis*10000.0)
            if index == -1: break
            count+= 1

            orig = location + axis*0.00001



        if (count%2 == 0):
            outside1 = True
            break




    axes = [ mathutils.Vector((0,1,0)) ]
    outside2 = False
    for axis in axes:

        mat1 = mathutils.Matrix(ob.matrix_world)
        mat=mat1.invert()

        orig = mat1*point


        count = 0
        while True:
            location,normal,index = ob.ray_cast(orig,axis*10000.0)
            if index == -1: break
            count+= 1

            orig = location + axis*0.00001



        if (count%2 == 0):
            outside2 = True
            break

    outside = outside1 or outside2
    return not outside




ob = bpy.context.active_object
M = 512
fileOut = 'D:\images\\maskFile.txt'

fo = open(fileOut , "w")
for n in range(0,M):
    for m in range(0,M):
        for l in range(0,M):
            if pointInsideMesh( mathutils.Vector(((l+1)/M-0.5,(m+1)/M-0.5,(n+1)/M-0.5)), ob ):
                fo.write("1")
            else:
                fo.write("0")
            if l < M-1:
                fo.write(" ")
        fo.write("\n") 
    fo.write("\n")          
fo.close()
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Update:

```
import mathutils, numpy, bpy

def pointInsideMesh(point,ob):
    return False

ob = bpy.context.active_object
M = 512
fileOut = 'D:\images\\maskFile.txt'

fo = open(fileOut , "w")
for n in range(0,M):
    for m in range(0,M):
        for l in range(0,M):
            if pointInsideMesh( mathutils.Vector(((l+1)/M-0.5,(m+1)/M-0.5,(n+1)/M-0.5)), ob ):
                fo.write("1")
            else:
                fo.write("0")
            if l < M-1:
                fo.write(" ")
        fo.write("\n") 
    fo.write("\n")          
fo.close()
```

reproduces the problem, but

```
import mathutils, numpy, bpy

def pointInsideMesh():
    return False

ob = bpy.context.active_object
M = 512
fileOut = 'D:\images\\maskFile.txt'

fo = open(fileOut , "w")
for n in range(0,M):
    for m in range(0,M):
        for l in range(0,M):
            if pointInsideMesh():
                fo.write("1")
            else:
                fo.write("0")
            if l < M-1:
                fo.write(" ")
        fo.write("\n") 
    fo.write("\n")          
fo.close()
```

does not, the only difference being that in the first example of these two, the location of the point being tested (and the object) is being passed to the function, while in the second example, no arguments are passed. In c++, even if you pass by value, the copy of the argument that is created within the function will be cleared from memory at the function return. But the arguments are passed differently in python, and this must be the source of the problem, as I don't really understand how this works.

Comment: In the two different versions at the end, mathutils.Vector looks suspicious to me. There is no way passing variables around would cause memory leak, unless the garbage collector is flaky.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem on Blender 3.6.5, btw.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can see that would be causing the memory leak would be the `ob` object.

You do something to that object `512^3` times. If `ob.ray_cast` stores some data on the `ob` object, then I could see that being a problem. Try replacing

```
ob.ray_cast(orig,axis*10000.0)
```

with 3 static values and see if the memory issue persists. There could be a memory leak on the C side of blender.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I first tried this, which didn't work, but I've since made more significant changes to try to pinpoint where this leak occurs. This can be seen in the update to my original question. Thanks again :)